# CreateMaterialTopTabNavigator how to add 3rd tab

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation

I'm learning react native and I did manage to get 2 tabbars up and running.
Now I'm trying to add a 3rd tabbar but every time I try to add a 3rd tabbar I only see 2 tabbars. I'm a little bit stuck and hope some one can help with some codeing.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    createMaterialTopTabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import FoldersList from '../screens/FoldersList';

const Routes = {
    Home: {
        screen: (props) => <FoldersList {...props} tabIndex={0}/>,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Home'
        }
    },
    MyNewTab: {
        screen: (props) => <FoldersList {...props} tabIndex={1} createFolderTitle='Create new tab folder' />,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'My New Tab'
        }
    },
        MyThirdTab: {
        screen: (props) => <FoldersList {...props} tabIndex={2} createFolderTitle='Create new tab folder' />,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'My Third Tab'
        }
    }
}

const routeConfig = {
    swipeEnabled: false
}

export default TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    ...Routes
}, routeConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a syntax error and it's probably not compiling. Change the following:

```js
export default TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
```

to

```js
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but that did not worked.